# How to Delete Node tag in the XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML like this

```
<DataBases>
  <DataBase Name="725" />
  <DataBase Name="425"/>
</DataBases>
```

I am trying to delete Name Tag 425, using below code.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList nodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("DataBase");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
       foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
       {
            if (attribute.Value == "425")
            {
                 node.RemoveAll();
                 break;
            }
       }
}
document.Save(fileName);
```

Result will be :

```
<DataBases>
  <DataBase Name="725" />
  <DataBase />
</DataBases>
```

only the Name Attribute deleted, I want to delete DataBase Tag also.

Correct result needed is :

```
<DataBases>
  <DataBase Name="725" />
</DataBases>
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: `node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);` (instead of `node.RemoveAll();`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML to parse and transform xml. Example is shown next:

```
var xml  ="<DataBases>\r\n  <DataBase Name=\"725\" />\r\n  <DataBase Name=\"425\"/>\r\n</DataBases>";
var root = XDocument.Parse(xml);

//removing all DataBase nodes with Name="425"
root.Descendants("DataBase")
    .Where(node => node.Attribute("Name").Value == "425")
    .Remove();

Console.WriteLine (root.ToString());
```

prints:

```
<DataBases>
  <DataBase Name="725" />
</DataBases>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LinqToXml

```
string xml = @"<DataBases>
                <DataBase Name=""725"" />
                <DataBase Name=""425""/>
                </DataBases>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

xDoc.Descendants("DataBase")
    .First(d => (string)d.Attribute("Name") == "425")
    .Remove();

string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList nodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("DataBase");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.GetAttrubute("Name") == "425")
    {
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        break;
    }
}
document.Save(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case loading for XMLDocument, Convert string to XML and XML string then save the file.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);
string str = document.OuterXml;
var root = XDocument.Parse(str);
root.Descendants("DataBase").Where(node => node.Attribute("Name").Value == "425").Remove();
XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
xm.LoadXml(root.ToString());
xm.Save(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
string fileName = "test.xml";
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("fileName");
string name = "425";
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("/DataBases/DataBase[@Name='" + name + "']");
if (node != null) node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
document.Save(fileName);
```